# Триггер на удаление нескольких объектов

Tags: sql-server

У меня есть триггер на удаление. Этот триггер добавляет запись в журнал логов если запись удаляется. Если удаляется только один объект то всё работает хорошо. Но если удалять больше 1, то получаю ошибку. Я прововал в триггере писать TOP(1), но и это не помогло. Как это можно решить? Мне необходимо, чтобы при каждом удалении записывалась запись в Logs

```
Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.
The statement has been terminated.


ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[AfterDeleteIssue]
   ON  [dbo].[NewspaperIssues] 
   AFTER DELETE
AS 
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Id INT = (SELECT Id FROM deleted)
    DECLARE @Data NVARCHAR(3000) = (SELECT 'DateOfPublication:' +  CAST(I.DateOfPublication as nvarchar) +
                                           ' Title:' + (SELECT Title FROM Polygraphies WHERE Id = @Id)
                                    FROM deleted I)
    INSERT INTO dbo.Logs([Description], ObjectIdentifier, UserName, TypeOfObject, [Data])
    VALUES('Deleted from a table "NewspaperIssues"', @Id, CURRENT_USER, 'Newspaper issue', @Data)
END
```

Comment: не используйте переменные, делайте `insert .... select ... from deleted`

Comment: @Mike не помогло

Comment: Я заменил все переменные на запросы, и эта же ошибка вновь всплыла

Comment: Не переменные на запросы. А единым запросом: `insert into table(поля,...) select 'Deleted from a table "NewspaperIssues"', id, ... from deleted`. Потому что когда вы указываете values - то можете передать только одну строку, и понятно, что в качестве единичного поля в ней не может быть несколько строк. Поэтому сначала создайте запрос select который сразу вернет все нужные строки, а потом напишите его _вместо_ values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как-то так:

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[AfterDeleteIssue]
   ON  [dbo].[NewspaperIssues] 
   AFTER DELETE
AS 
BEGIN

INSERT INTO dbo.Logs([Description], ObjectIdentifier, UserName, TypeOfObject, [Data])
SELECT 'Deleted from a table "NewspaperIssues"',
    d.Id,
    CURRENT_USER,
    'Newspaper issue',
    'DateOfPublication:' +  CAST(d.DateOfPublication as nvarchar) + ' Title:' + ISNULL(p.Title, '')
FROM deleted d
    LEFT JOIN Polygraphies p ON p.Id = d.Id

END
```

Обращаю внимание, что не указывать размерность поля как здесь: `CAST(d.DateOfPublication as nvarchar)` это плохой стиль